# Converting Distance using C#

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, build

**Program Problem:** I am trying to convert from one type of distance to the next after the user inputs the data. The user must select from one list to convert to the other list in distance. For example, selecting inches in one list to convert to yards in another list.

**My code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Distance_Converter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void ConvertButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //int Inches = 1;
            //int Feet = 12;
            //int Yards = 36;
            int distance_to_convert;
            string lengthOption1;
            string lengthOption2;
            int inches_feet;
            int inches_yard;

            lengthOption1 = FromListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            lengthOption2 = ToListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            distance_to_convert = int.Parse(distancetoconvertTextBox.Text);

            if ((FromListBox.SelectedIndex) != -1 && (ToListBox.SelectedIndex) != -1)   
            {
                switch (lengthOption1)
                {
                    case "Inches":
                        if (lengthOption2 == "Inches")
                        {
                            //object distancetoconvert = null;
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox = distance_to_convert.ToString();
                        }
                        else if (lengthOption2 == "Feet")
                        {
                            inches_feet = distance_to_convert / 12;
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox = inches_feet.ToString();
                        }
                        else if (lengthOption2 == "Yards")
                        {
                            inches_yard = distance_to_convert / 36;
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox = inches_yard.ToString();
                        }
                        break;
                    case "Feet":
                        if (lengthOption2 == "Inches")
                        {
                            int feet_inches = distance_to_convert * 12;
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox = feet_inches.ToString();
                        }
                        else if (lengthOption2 == "Feet")
                        {
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox = distance_to_convert.ToString(); ;
                        }
                        else if (lengthOption2 == "Yards")
                        {
                            int feet_yard = distance_to_convert / 3;
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox = feet_yard.ToString();
                        }
                        break;

                    case "Yards":
                        if (lengthOption2 == "Inches")
                        {
                            int Yards_inches = distance_to_convert * 36;
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox = Yards_inches.ToString();
                        }
                        else if (lengthOption2 == "Feet")
                        {
                            int Yards_feet = distance_to_convert * 3;
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox = Yards_feet.ToString();
                        }
                        else if (lengthOption2 == "Yards")
                        {
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox = distance_to_convert.ToString(); ;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
        private void Exitbutton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**My dilemma:** The code looks correct in every sense. However, when I try to convert from int to string on multiple occasions the IDE gives me a red line. The code won't compile and creates build errors. I am thinking that I will have to create a separate class to convert from int to string.

The error states: "Error    CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' "

It appears on line - 42, 47, 52, or any line that begins with ConvertedDistanceTextBox = .

My apologies, I am new to coding and I am trying to learn.  And I am relatively new to stackoverflow.

Comment: You should try to read the error and understand what it means. In this case I suppose that you are trying to assign your calculated value to a TextBox. You should assign the Text property of the TextBox instead IE: _ConvertedDistanceTextBox.Text = ......;_

Comment: Do you think the errors you see are irrelavant and didn't post them? This is why I vote to close: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself*

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. The wiggly red lines indicate an error. If you hover with the mouse over them, a tooltip will explain the error (alternatively, try compiling your program, and the error messages will be listed in the Output window). It's no fun if you throw code at us and ask us to figure out by ourselves which of the lines in your whole code produce wiggly red lines for whatever reasons ;-)

Comment: @ Steve 55- the error states "CS0029  C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'". However, I am using the correct syntax- TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.Text = "Default text";

Comment: What is _ConvertedDistanceTextBox_? It is a TextBox? If yes your code is wrong because you don't assign the property Text but you try to assign a string to a Control of type TextBox

Comment: @ABerrio, do not explain your question here in the comments. Edit and improve the question itself. It is a bad idea to bury important information about your problem deep in the comments...

Comment: @Steve,elgonzo, eser,; thank you for the helpful tips. I will definitely properly ask questions in a better format in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You should set your string values to the text property of your textbox

```
ConvertedDistanceTextBox.Text = inches_yard.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I appreciate this. I completely overlooked this minor error. @ Mats